# Convension for debug string and representation string

Tags: java, conventions

Hi I am writing a satisifiability checker and I have a `Literal` class
I need:

a method for showing a `Literal`'s details/states

a method for displaying the raw user input's `Literal`.
 

But there is only one `toString` method. Which one should I put in the `toString` and which one should I create a new method for? Is there a convention for this type of stuff? If yes is there a reason?

**Update**
My details/states string looks like:

```
String.format("Full literal: %s, raw literal: %s, negated: %s, " +
              "tautology: %s, contradiction: %s, assigned: %s",
                this.fullLiteral, this.rawLiteral, 
                this.isNegated,   this.isTautology,
                this.isContradiction, this.isAssigned ? this.truthValue : "null");
```

My raw literal string looks like:

```
return String.format("Raw literal: %s", this.rawLiteral);
```

Comment: Can you show some examples of the two kind of string representations? I would usually return the machine readable one in `toString`, and create a separate method for the human-readable one.

Comment: I would use `toString()` for the detailed one, and something like `getRaw()` for the raw. But I feel this question might be either too broad/opinion-based.

Comment: @Sweeper I have added my example in the question

Comment: You generally use toString() to provide an easier way for the developer to know what the object represents and contains. If you think both the raw literal value and the other details are useful, just return both in the toString().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString())

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object. The result should be a concise but informative representation that is easy for a person to read. It is recommended that all subclasses override this method.

This may support my comment about using `toString()` for getting a detailed string (and consequently having a different method, like `getRaw()` for getting the raw data)